# NodeJS equivalent of a curl request

Tags: node.js, http, curl, request

I am trying to convert a curl request to a nodeJS script, but somehow it fails on me., by failing means, that the url I setup with cloudflare triggers a captcha whilst it doesn't when I use the curl request I copied from dev tools > network tab.

here is the curl

```
curl -q 'https://foo.bar/path' -H 'cookie: somecookie' -H 'origin: https://foo.bar' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://foo.bar/path' -H 'authority: www.foo.bar' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' --data "foo=bazz" --compressed
```

and here is the nodeJS code

```
var request = require('request');
var url = 'https://foo.bar/path';
var cookie = 'somecookie';
var ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36';

var baseRequest = request.defaults({
  headers: {
    'Cookie': cookie,
    'User-Agent': ua,
    'origin': 'https://foo.bar',
    'referer': 'https://foo.bar/path'
  }
});

baseRequest.post({ url: url, formData: {
  foo: 'bazz'
}}, function(err, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: You can take a network sniffer and examine both the CURL and the node.js request and see exactly what is different between the two.  The http request is plain text so it should be all there for you to see.

Answer (score 9):

There are some online tools that doing it for you like https://curl.trillworks.com/#node

by the way I did for you and the result is :

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
    'cookie': 'somecookie',
    'origin': 'https://foo.bar',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'referer': 'https://foo.bar/path',
    'authority': 'www.foo.bar',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};

var dataString = 'foo=bazz';

var options = {
    url: 'https://foo.bar/path',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Comment: The [trillworks](https://curl.trillworks.com/#node) tool is great!  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent website. It does not give code for -F option though.

Answer (score 1):

```
exec(`curl -q 'https://foo.bar/path' -H 'cookie: somecookie' -H 'origin: https://foo.bar' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt;q=0.8' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://foo.bar/path' -H 'authority: www.foo.bar' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' --data "foo=bazz" --compressed`
, (error, result, metadata) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
```

You can do direct CURL using `exec`

Answer (score 1):

From ES6, you can make use of the async/await to ececute a child process with curl. Here's a simple example:

```
const { exec: execAsync } = require('child-process-async');

const { result, stderr } = await execAsync(`curl -s https://api.ipdata.co/country_name?api-key=test`);
console.log(result);
```